# Can't load cast_framework.js on Chrome Sender

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

So a couple of month back I wrote a test sender to get some experience with Cast senders. It worked fine and I could send images and videos to my Chromecasts.

I now need to create a custom receiver and I wanted to use my old sender to test my receiver code. However, my sender doesn't work anymore eventhough I didn't change anything since then.

The errors i'm now getting in Chrome's console are the following:

> - GET file://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/sender/1.0/cast_framework.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
> - Uncaught ReferenceError: cast is not defined
>   at window.__onGCastApiAvailable (script.js:84)
>   at chrome.cast.cb (cast_sender.js:99)

When I look at the "Network" tab I can see that the *cast_framework.js* file failed to load after 22s.

I then tried to use the [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome) on Google's Github to see if it was my sender that was at fault but I get the same error.

I also can reach the devices with the Cast button in Chrome's menu.

What is going on with that file? Is it my browser that has a problem? Is it my devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was the following:
As you can see the browser was looking for the file with `file://`. This happens because I launched my HTML file locally so the url in the browser was `file:///home/.../index.html` and I guess when it loads the framework file it guesses that it has to use `file://` too instead of `html://`.
Someone told me that I should serve the file from a server so I made a brief Node server with express.static to serve the file and it then worked again when I loaded the page via `localhost:4000`.

I still don't know how it worked a couple of month ago but I guess I was just lucky in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Upon checking, this file below is visible:

**www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/sender/1.0/cast_framework.js**

You might want to try putting these codes inside your head tag in your html file that calls **"script.js"**:

Check this [Github Guide](https://github.com/markknol/hx-googlecast-externs)

> Include the cast_sender.js  tag
>
> Add the script tag to your HTML page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/sender/1.0/cast_framework.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok so I had this `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>` in my code that didn't work.    
I replaced that line by your 2 lines but I still get the error. However this time the load failure happens 1ms after refreshing the page, not 22s as before. It is still _cast_framework.js_ that fails...

Comment: Used following  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/sender/1.0/cast_framework.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script> It worked.